# running a maven scala project

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

Im starting to learn scala and mongo , my IDE is intellij IDEA. I created a scala project using

```
mvn:archetype-generate
```

and typed a simple hello world program in the IDEA with some arithmetic options such as

```
println(5)
val i = 1+2
println(i)
```

Then i compiled it using

mvn compile

It said

```
build success
```

But now how should i execute my application and verify the output. There isn't a single article which explains how to start off with scala,maven,idea and i am entirely new to all of this. any help would be useful for me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### maven-exec-plugin

Try with this code:

```
package com.example

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(5)
        val i = 1 + 2
        println(i)
    }
}
```

Place it under `/src/main/scala/com/example/Main.scala` and run it using:

```
$ mvn package exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.Main
```

If you don't want to pass `mainClass` manually, you can do this in plugin configuration:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

There are other possibilities, this is the easiest one. Of course in IntelliJ you should be able to run the program directly.

### maven-jar-plugin

If you want to ship the application, use `maven-jar-plugin` to add `Main-Class` and `Class-Path` entries to the manifest:

```
Main-Class: com.example.Main
Class-Path: lib/scala-library-2.9.0-1.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar ...
```

The following configuration does that and also copies all the dependencies (including Scala runtime library) to `target/lib`.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
                <customClasspathLayout>lib/$${artifact.artifactId}-$${artifact.version}$${dashClassifier?}.$${artifact.extension}
                </customClasspathLayout>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now you can simply run your application by (note the `target/lib` directory is required):

```
$ java -jar target/your_app-VERSION.jar
```

You can ship your application simply by copying your JAR file along with `/lib` subdirectory.

Also see [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) and [Playing with Scala and Maven](http://prystash.blogspot.com/2009/08/playing-with-scala-and-maven.html).

Comment: so i have to provide the entry point of my project here and it doesnt matter how big my project is right?

Comment: Are you asking do you always have to specify `mainClass`? No, you can hardcode it in your `pom.xml`. Also see my edits for other options.

Comment: I've been trying to get maven to set the classpath for an hour now! Was only missing <customClasspathLayout>....ahhhhh. ta

Comment: Tried `mvn package exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.Main`, works like charm. Thank you